# Use the locally published RA route for routing

Tags: routing, radvd

I have a Linux machine, working as a router, that has `radvd` configured. I have set up some basic configuration like the following:

```
interface wpan0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;

    prefix 2001:db8:200::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on; 
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
};

interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;

    route 2001:db8:200::/64 {};
}
```

From other machines in the same `eth0`-network, I see the proper route:

```
$ ip -6 route
2001:db8:200::/64 via fe80::dead:beef:dead:beef dev enp11s0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

But the machine that is advertising that route does not have that in its routing table. Is there a proper mechanism to add that? I thought that I could avoid to manually meddle the routing table, as to avoid duplicating config things. Maybe I am missing some thing to make it work? Or maybe it is not the proper way to do it? [why?]

Answer (score 1):

You would get such a route automatically by configuring an interface with an IP address and prefix in that network, which suggests to me that this has not been done. If your network interface or design does not permit this, you would need to add a route yourself.